# numpy.concatenate with weird (3,) shaped array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What does it mean when numpy.shape returns a partially empty shape and why can't I concatenate it with another array?  For instance:

```
In: print h_labels.shape
    print Thood0_48.shape
    print np.concatenate((Thood0_48,h_labels),axis=1).shape

Out: (400,)
     (400, 48)

     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
     <ipython-input-403-97b371dd2547> in <module>()
     1 print h_labels.shape
     2 print Thood0_48.shape
     ----> 3 print np.concatenate((Thood0_48,h_labels),axis=1).shape

     ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Beyond just the answer to the concatenate question, what is the fundamental difference between an array with shape (400,1) and one with shape (400,)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `(400,)` array is a 1D array (row vector). The comma is just there to denote a tuple- for example type `(400)` and `(400,)` into the interpreter. A `(400,1)` array is a 2D array of shape 400 rows and 1 column (column vector). Functions that automatically change the shape of the array such as `vstack` and `hstack` still call concatenate, but with additional python overhead (e.g. [vstack source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/core/shape_base.py#L179)).

Either of the following will work:

```
np.concatenate((Thood0_48[:, None], h_labels), axis=1)
np.vstack((Thood0_48, h_labels.T)).T
```

I would say the former is a better solution, but the latter demonstrates the `vstack` function.